# Insecure APIs (_memcpy) can still be found in the iOS Application

Tags: swift, memcpy, otool

We have developed an IOS application and found that the application binary file is using _malloc() function somewhere inside.

```
otool MyAppName -Iv | grep _malloc
0x00000001008dd812 155991 _malloc
0x000000010092d9b0 155991 _malloc

otool MyAppName -Iv | grep_memcpy   
0x00000001008dd818 155992 _memcpy   
0x000000010092d9b8 155992 _memcpy
```

[image]

We have not used malloc() function from inside our code.
Not sure why this symbol is present within our binary.
How can check that function usage or how can we remove this memcpy from our binary?

Comment: hi.. is this already fixed? i am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are panicking about nothing. Memcpy is perfectly safe when used to copy data from one location to another. It does exactly what it says on the tin. If a developer is too stupid to use it properly, tough.

If you look at any “safer” alternative, they will check parameters and either refuse the operation or call memcpy. So you *will* have memcpy somewhere.

Same with malloc. What do you think gets called when you allocate a new object in C++, Objective-C or Swift, or for a std::vec or NSArray?